# How to show the Loader image like in gmail when loading Data into GridView?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Could any one help how to show the loader image when the data is loading ?I did a sample one which is not a perfect one.Please suggest me the best way .I have a question can we use jquery or javascript?Here when i click the load the data has to load to GV in between this process the preloader has to be visible like in GMAIL.[image: Like this Process]
[image: Demo Picture]

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Loader Image While Loading Data in GV.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Loader_Image_While_Loading_Data_in_GV" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Loader Image While Loading Data in GV</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="load_img" runat="server" Height="70px" Width="70px" ImageUrl="~/Images/ajax-loader_green.gif"
                        Visible="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnload" runat="server" Text="Load" OnClick="btnload_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan"
                        BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Code behind i wrote like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AdventureWorksModel;

public partial class Loader_Image_While_Loading_Data_in_GV : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    AdventureWorksEntities awe = new AdventureWorksEntities();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        load_img.Visible = true;
        gv1.DataSource = awe.CountryRegionCurrencies.ToList();
        gv1.DataBind();
        load_img.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loader image is usually used to notify user that some **Ajax** activities are running.

I would suggest you to wrap your `GridView` with [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<!-- You must always add a ScriptManager control -->
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />



<td>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnLoad" eventname="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>

</form>
```

Everything inside UpdatePanel's ContentTemplate will be updated when the UpdatePanel's Triggger is occured (in this case, when user click `btnLoad` button)

Now, you need to add [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.aspx) to inform user that the server side processing is still progressing.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
    <!-- it doesn't have to be asp Image control -->
    <img src="Images/ajax-loader_green.gif" alt="" />
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

you can put it anywhere.

example of usage, [read this blog](http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/mostlydevelopers/blog/post/2008/08/23/Show-UpdateProgress-when-using-an-UpdatePanel-with-Triggers.aspx)

Comment: But i click for the next time automatically am getting the values from Cache.Can we do this using javascript or jquery?

Comment: If it is cached on server, then it should be another question. Did you get your image loader yet?

Comment: If you're getting output from Output cache, it's a server side problem. doing Ajax with jQuery or javascript will not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following small jQuery plugin.
It centers the loading image in the middle of the specified container (vertically and horizontally):
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CenterImage

Demo site:
http://www.demosites.somee.com/demos/centerimage.html

Usage:
This plugin positions a loading image centrally over a specified html container (div, span...).

Currently available configuration settings:

```
{ path: "../Images/ajax.gif", overlayColor: 'green', opacity: 0.2, zindex: 2000, isrelative:true }
```

Minimum configuration for initialization:

```
$('.4th').CenterImage({ path: "../Images/ajax-bar.gif" });
```

Call this, in order to remove the loading image (and the overlay)

```
$('.4th').CenterImage('remove');
```